# mailto href body not showing full data sent

Tags: php, html, email, url, mailto

Hello I have URL that looks like this,

`http://domain.com?collection=Fashion%20Forward&room=LS1&scene=Scene%20III`

This is first created with space, which I string replace with PHP.

What I am wanting to is click a link and open the mail client with the above link in the body of the email, therefore I am doing the following,

```
<a href="mailto:?body=http://domain.com?collection=Fashion%20Forward&room=LS1&scene=Scene%20III">Email</a>
```

When the mail client opens the URL is getting cut short and I am only see,

`?collection=Fashion Forward` why would the whole not be getting put int he body of the email?

Answer (score 2):

In the same way that the `%20` is an encoded space, you need to encode the `&` and `=` too.

Are you using [PHP's URL encode](https://www.php.net/urlencode)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?subject=Your%20Subject&body=http://domain.com?collection=Fashion%20Forward%26room=LS1%26scene=Scene%20III">Email</a>
```